# CruiseControl user/password

Tags: java, cruisecontrol

I'm trying to add user/password to my working cruisecontrol instance but it doesn't have the desired affect - I can still click "force build" on the dashboard interface. Is this user/password configuration only for the http://:8080/cruisecontrol page and not the dashboard? Is there any way to add security to the dashboard?

Here's the java call from the shell script:

/opt/java/jdk1.6.0_22/bin/java -Djavax.management.builder.initial=mx4j.server.MX4JMBeanServerBuilder -Dcc.library.dir=/opt/tools/cruisecontrol-bin-2.8.4/lib -Djetty.logs/cc_logs -Ddashboard.config=/dashboard-config.xml -Dcc.logdir=/cc_logs -Dcc.artifacts=/home/WCM-LONDON/kxdev/CC/cc_artifacts -jar /opt/tools/cruisecontrol-bin-2.8.4/lib/cruisecontrol-launcher.jar -configfile /config.xml -jmxport 8000 -webport 8080 -rmiport 1099 -user x -password y

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the original java version then the short answer is no.

In order to have this functionality you would have to implement it and rebuild the cruisecontrol.jar file.

However Cruisecontrol.net supports what you are looking for e.g. [Role permissions in CC.NET](http://build.sharpdevelop.net/ccnet/doc/CCNET/Role%20Permission.html)